# Use of Max-Width In Fluid (Or Responsive) Web Design

Tags: css, user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience

I see that a lot of fluid websites use a min-width and max-width property on their web pages designed mainly for desktop. When the browser width is less than min-width, content stops shrinking and the user has to scroll horizontally. I can relate to the rationele behind it. As far as I understand, it basically means that the content is designed so that shrinking its width past this point will make it unusable. It is acceptable, because that page is designed with a minimum width in mind.

But I cannot fully understand the use of max-width property on the main content. These websites usually limit the growth of the content container and center it. Why not let it fill the screen since you are already using percentages instead of pixel values? Web sites like Outlook or Gmail fill the screen whereas a lot like Amazon choose to limit the width and center the content.

Comment: Good question. UX Stack Exchange (ux.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing more than a design decision. Or maybe they were not implemented to support such wide viewports that could make the site to look broken.

In terms of user experience, it can be hard to read text when the lines are too wide so making shorter, leaner paragraphs make sense.